# Program file deleted while running

Tags: front-end

I have a program running for some time at one computer. Today, unintentionally, I edited the program file from another computer (I use Dropbox), and the program kept running. Trying to correct my mistake, I deleted the program file, and, from the computer it was running, saved it again.

My question is: have I ruined the evaluation? Should I start over or Mathematica can deal with such situation?

My concern is that I do not know how long the evaluation will take, and it can be some months.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the "program file" is your notebook you should be OK. The code in the frontend does not affect the code that has been sent to the kernel for evaluation, those two are separate programs. However you should try to find a way to save intermediate results. I wouldn't count on Mathematica working non-stop for months.

Comment: Pickett, thank you. And yes, my program file is a .nb. The evaluation I am waiting for is a single command, which is simplifying a big expression that should be zero.